# Another dimensions

Tags: spacetime, curvature, spacetime-dimensions

Just a science ponderer, and pretty much interested in physics. Please guide me if I am wrong.

There have been many statements made by the physicists about the existence of other dimensions (particularly 11) except forward,sideward, upward and time; upon which this universe works. They believe that these dimensions are so small and curled up that we are not able to see or experience them.

I am wondering wether curvature can be one of them. Let me give a real life example:- earth is almost a sphere, I hope we all agree with this. So when we travel from equator to South pole (by land), we have actually travelled 90degrees on the Earth's curved surface but then also we don't quite feel the curvature of the earth. It seems that we have travelled a straight path. On the other hand if we had to travel 90 deg. On another sphere which was smaller in size of the earth we would feel the curvature of that ball.

Another thing is that if the mass of the other ball was the same as the earth then we would feel the gravity on the ball more conciously as compared to earth.

So from the above experiences can we conclude that the curvature of the object will be more when the angle created between two tangents from two consecutive point on the surface is less.and hence curvature is inversely proportional to the angle of curva ture and also gravity is inversely proportional to the angle of curvature and directly proportional to the curvature.

I you have any answer please let me know in simple language as I am still a school student and can't understand complex terms.

Comment: *I am wondering wether curvature can be one of them.* What does your argument about curvature have to do with dimensions? Those paragraphs don’t even include the word “dimension”. Also, string theory doesn’t predict 10 or 11 *extra* dimensions; it predicts 10 or 11 *total* dimensions where 6 or 7 of them are curled up.

Comment: The number of dimensions is the number of coordinates required to identify an event in spacetime. Curvature is not a coordinate. Also, in 4D there are 20 independent curvature components!

Comment: @Ghoster I presumed what he meant was that locally the Earth looks flat -- he missed the part where this is what the fundamental meaning of a manifold is; we can do Euclidean mathematics locally. What he talked about is the essential notion of curvature in geometry, but not dimensions. And the dimensionality aspect is something many people mess up on. This is the issue with people like Michio Kaku or Brain Greene popularizing physics -- they never seem to get it right. They mean well, but they don't talk about why there are tons of details left out because it is a complicated subject.

Comment: @VaibhavK *locally the Earth looks flat* Yes, but locally the surface of a marble or a mustard seed is also flat.

Comment: @suchit-mehta I would recommend reading an introductory text on differential geometry and for general relativity to understand these things. String theory _does_ predict higher dimensions, but there are a number of reasons why. Your question is missing a basic point, but I would recommend you understand what it is missing yourself, since it is a trivial thing. Being a school student does not mean anything -- I myself just graduated high school. Your mathematical drive is what matters.

Comment: @VaibhavK *I myself just graduated high school.* Wow! I would not have thought that based on your collection of answers.

Answer (score 2):

Dimensions denote the number of variables needed to describe exactly where something is located. But this happens inside some given space (like the Earth's surface which is 2 dimensional or the universe which has 3 space dimensions and one time dimension). Curvature describes how much a space deviates from being flat. So normally it has nothing to do with dimensions, beyond that defining curvature depends a lot on how many dimensions the space have.

Sometimes you can use different variables to describe a space. If we assume Earth had temperature that was a simple, increasing function of latitude we could use temperature instead of latitude to describe location, and we could use the time when the sun is exactly in the south instead of longitude. There are likely some surfaces where one could use curvature instead of a normal coordinate to uniquely pinpoint a location. But it would be a rather peculiar way of doing it.